# Why are unanswered questions always getting upvotes but no answers?

Tags: discussion, support

[My question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811299/ubuntu-squashfs-errors) has only upvotes but no answers, yet no comments. It's just a distant dessert I guess.

Why is it so inactive?

Comment: It is not inactive, it has 3 votes and 50 odd views, that’s above average but issue likely is that not many people use `squashfs` so the amount of people that could answer is low. On top of that, you provided a big list of things you tried (not a bad thing) and that takes up many of the suggestions people would have. Your question is just very niche IMO. Keep being patient, some questions get answerd monthes after being posted.

Comment: @MarkKirby I fear that Community is going to delete it as RemoveDeadQuestions

Comment: Huh? We don't remove questions just for been unanswered for 10 days, only if they become irreverent after a long time (years, like eol questions), no one will delete a perfectly good question just because it is unanswered.

Comment: Here is an unanswered q from me from 2013, no one deleted it even though it is completely irrelevant today and unanswered for 3 years. http://askubuntu.com/questions/175500/why-does-ubuntu-ignore-my-xorg-conf

Comment: For one thing, because if unanswered questions got answers, they wouldn't be unanswered anymore. :P

Comment: «but no answers» It seems to me some users on this site think that *everyone* know the answer to everything and if no answer is given then it is weird. Actually, it would be awesome if we knew everything, but we don't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Short answer

*Voting* for questions and *answering* are two (completely) different things:

- I *vote* for a question if the issue is well explained, well documented and the question shows some effort to find a solution/to analyze the issue. Whether I have knowledge on the subject or not is irrelevant then.
- I *answer* a question if I am pretty sure I can offer a working solution or a useful insight.

Comment: I guess my question was so good that they went away before my question blinded them. Haha, great answer. +1 and a big green tick!

Answer (score 4):

In view of the fact that you have already tried many of the common and easy solutions, the margin of people who can attempt an answer at your question is greatly diminished.  That's also why it is getting up-votes: if you hover over the upvote button, it says:

> This question shows research effort, it is useful and clear.

Your question indeed does show research effort, **which is a good thing**.  Therefore, it gets upvotes.  However, your potential responders are diminished.  If you want to get more potential responders, you can start a bounty on the question: it gives more incentive for those who could potentially find the answer to your question to search a bit longer.

## TL;DR:

The first responders can't perform surgeries.  If you want a surgery, you either have to wait, pay a bunch, or a combination of both.

Comment: I already did. Hats off to @JorgeCastro for the 200 bounty :D

Comment: Hmm, good point, @MarkKirby.  Now that that's been brought to light, I agree that it doesn't deserve upvotes...  However, when I wrote the answer, that wasn't clear...  :(

Comment: I know, that's why I still voted for you :)